# How to do a matrix transition in Python with dates and Ids?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this in Python:

| Dates | Students | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-24 | 1 | 7 |
| 2017-04-24 | 2 | 8 |
| 2017-04-24 | 3 | 10 |
| 2017-04-24 | 4 | 4 |
| 2019-04-25 | 1 | 2 |
| 2019-04-25 | 2 | 5 |
| 2019-04-25 | 3 | 6 |
| 2019-04-25 | 4 | 8 |
| 2018-01-07 | 1 | 2 |
| 2018-01-07 | 2 | 3 |
| 2018-01-07 | 3 | 6 |
| 2018-01-07 | 4 | 7 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I only have 38 different dates, so my aim is to make a matrix transition of de evolution of the Students score in the next 3 dates. The range of the scores is [0,10].

And the final matrix looks like this:

(Matrix Next 3 observations)

| Initial Scores/Scores in 3 Observations | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60% | 20% | 10% | 5% | 1% | 0 | 0 | ... | ... | ... | 100% |
| 2 | 10% | 50% | 10% | 5% | 5% | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 100% |
| 3 | ... | 5% | 40% | 5% |  | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 100% |
| 4 | ... |  | 10% | 60% | 5% |  |  |  |  |  | 100% |
| 5 | ... |  |  | ... | 80% | ... |  |  |  |  | 100% |
| 6 | ... |  |  |  | ... | 40% | ... |  |  |  | 100% |
| 7 | ... |  |  |  |  | ... | 50% | ... |  |  | 100% |
| 8 | ... |  |  |  |  |  | ... | 90% | ... |  | 100% |
| 9 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... | 55% | ... | 100% |
| 10 | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ... | 50% | 100% |

In this matrix the row 1 we have all the students that get a score of 1 and in the next 3 dates, we can see that the 60% of them still have 1, but 20% have a 2 and 10% a 3.

I know that the first step is to add a tag number to every date.

I've tried with:

`df['tag_date'] = df['date'].diff().dt.days.ne(0).cumsum()`

| Dates | Students | Score | tag_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-04-24 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 2017-04-24 | 2 | 8 | 2 |
| 2017-04-24 | 3 | 10 | 3 |
| 2017-04-24 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 2019-04-25 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2019-04-25 | 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 2019-04-25 | 3 | 6 | 7 |
| 2019-04-25 | 4 | 8 | 8 |
| 2018-01-07 | 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 2018-01-07 | 2 | 3 | 10 |
| 2018-01-07 | 3 | 6 | 11 |
| 2018-01-07 | 4 | 7 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

But it doesn't work, it adds a tag to every date and doesn't matter that the date is the same or not.

The Next step is to calculate a new column with the score of the next 3 observations and then, we can do a Dcast or equivalent to get the matrix.

Can someone help me please? I'll be very greatful. If you need more code to understand my task, I'll add it.

Comment: In the final matrix, what does the first column represents?

Comment: The initial scores, and the columns the scores in the next 3 observations.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample set each student has a score on each date so I am not sure I understand your "offsetting" picture. But hopefully this gets you close to what you want

to be clear I am using this df:

```
data = StringIO('''
date    student score
2017-04-24  1   7
2017-04-24  2   8
2017-04-24  3   10
2017-04-24  4   4
2019-04-25  1   2
2019-04-25  2   5
2019-04-25  3   6
2019-04-25  4   8
2018-01-07  1   2
2018-01-07  2   3
2018-01-07  3   6
2018-01-07  4   7
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
```

Then we define the `tag_date` as such (and also drop `date` to avoid clutter):

```
df['tag_date'] = df['date'].ne(df['date'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.drop(columns = 'date')
```

Then we can simply `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['student', 'tag_date']).unstack()
```

output:

```
            score
tag_date    1   2   3
student         
1           7   2   2
2           8   5   3
3           10  6   6
4           4   8   7
```

Here for each student (row index) you see his score for each of the dates of the exams. You can do your percentages from here I suppose